# ContinueWith for a Task of unknown generic type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dynamic, task, continuewith

I have a method that gets a `Task<T>` where T is unknown at compile time and an `IAsyncDisposable`. I need to return a `Task<T>` which automatically disposes the disposable object after the original task has been completed.

This is what I came up with so far, but it is throwing a compile time Error

```
private static TResult AutoDispose<TResult>(TResult result, IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
{
    Func<dynamic, dynamic> continuationFunction = async t => { await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync(); return ((dynamic)t).Result; };
    var autoDisposing = ((dynamic)result).ContinueWith(continuationFunction);
    return (TResult)autoDisposing;
}
```

The Error, I'm getting is

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<dynamic, dynamic>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func<dynamic, dynamic>'.

I already tried different combinations of `dynamic` and `Task` but was unable to create a working solution. I'm always getting compile- or runtime errors.

**EDIT**

Because it seems to be confusing why I'm doing it this way:

I'm using this inside an `IAsyncQueryProvider`s `ExecuteAsync` method. The Interface defines the methods Signature as following

```
public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

Based on this, I know `TResult` is either of type `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` or `Task<T>`. I already wrote code to handle the case when it is an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` but I'm still struggling when it is a `Task<T>`.

Comment: Please post an example of where you use your `AutoDispose` method.

Comment: Generally speaking it's a bad idea to mix `dynamic` with generics. They're very different things. I think it's best to avoid `dynamic` entirely because it defeats the point of using a statically-typed language like C# in the first place.

Comment: "*T is unknown at compile time and an*", I actually cant get past this statement, its seems fairly incorrect. Generics ***ARE*** compiled in at compile time, they ***HAVE*** to be known.

Comment: @TheGeneral `T` is unknown at compile-time if you're building a library with open generics.

Comment: @Dai do mean an *unbound generic type*? However, they cant be used in any sort of expression other than `typeof`... Edit... ahh ok, cancel that, i see what you are saying. good point. :)

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear why I'm using it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `async`, the compile-time result type must be `Task` (or a tasklike). Nested tasks are normal using `ContinueWith` with `async` continuations; `Unwrap` is one solution. [If you can avoid `ContinueWith` completely, that's even better](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), but I believe in this case that would require quite a bit of tedious generics work.

Something like this should work:

```
private static TResult AutoDispose<TResult>(TResult result, IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable) // where TResult: Task<T>
{
  Func<dynamic, Task<TResult>> continuationFunction = async () => { await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync(); return result; };
  var continuation = ((dynamic)result).ContinueWith(continuationFunction, TaskScheduler.Default);
  var newResult = TaskExtensions.Unwrap(continuation);
  return (TResult)newResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
private static async Task<TResult> AutoDispose<TResult>( this Task<TResult> task )
    where TResult : IAsyncDisposable
{
    TResult result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    if( result != null )
    {
        await result.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = new HttpClient()
    .GetAsync( "/foo" )
    .AutoDispose();

HttpResponseMessage resp = await task;
// `resp` will be in a disposed state at this point.
```

Comment: The `AutoDispose` method cannot be async and must return `TResult` and not `Task<TResult>` also `TResult` is of type `Task<T>`, so wrapping it would result in something like `Task<Task<T>>`. I'm using this inside an AsyncQueryProviders `Execute` method, so I have these constraints.